# Laravel Editing post doesn't work

Tags: laravel

There are routes

```
Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('get-random-post', 'PostsController@getRandomPost');
Route::post('posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::post('publish', 'PostsController@publish');
Route::post('unpublish', 'PostsController@unpublish');
Route::post('delete', 'PostsController@delete');
Route::post('restore', 'PostsController@restore');
Route::post('change-rating', 'PostsController@changeRating');

Route::get('dashboard/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::put('dashboard/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@update');

Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('dashboard/posts/{id}', 'DashboardController@show')->name('dashboard.show');
Route::get('dashboard/published', 'DashboardController@published');
Route::get('dashboard/deleted', 'DashboardController@deleted');
```

methods in PostsController

```
public function edit($id) 
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);  
    return view('dashboard.edit', compact('post'));
}

public function update($id, PostRequest $request) 
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
}
```

but when I change post and click submit button, I get an error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

What's wrong? How to fix it?

**upd**

opening of the form from the view

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['method'=> 'PATCH', 'action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'id' => 'edit-post']) !!}
```

and as result I get

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mytestsite/dashboard/posts?6" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="edit-post"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="aiDh4YNQfLwB20KknKb0R9LpDFNmArhka0X3kIrb">
```

but why this action `http://mytestsite/dashboard/posts?6` ???

Comment: You don't have a route with the name **dashboard.show**

Comment: I added name to route, but error stays the same

Comment: You use the PUT method to update your post, so make sure you have a `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` in your form

Comment: You get error on which route (which URL is in browser when error appears)?

Comment: @KuKeC I updated question

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `patch` instead of `put` in your route for updating.

> Just a small tip you can save energy and a bit of time by declaring the Model in your parameters like this:

```
public function update(Post $id, PostRequest $request)
```

and get rid of this

```
 $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
```

> EDIT

You can use url in your form instead of action :

```
'url'=> '/mytestsite/dashboard/posts/{{$post->id}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the most probable reason is the mismatch between action and route. Maybe route requires POST method, but the action is GET. Check it.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: @Sebastian Maybe you are right. But without the exact code, i think it's a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send post id in hidden input, don't use smt like that 'action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id] 
It contribute to result action url.

Comment: why not? what's a problem with such `action`?